# Jquery Validation Plugin - Fields still producing errors

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html, validation

I have a checkbox field which determines whether the proceeding client ID field has an attribute of data-validate required:true, or data-validate required:false which drives my forms validation.

```
<input type="text" name="stID" id="stID" data-validate="required:true" />
```

Using jquery i can change the requirement in real-time, along with show/hide and add/remove the error classes associated with that field.

```
$("#input[name='stID']").attr("data-validate","required:false");
var form=$("#standard");
form.validate().resetForm();
```

The issue lies when someone tries to submit the form, then changes the initial checkbox option (if true, ID isn't required otherwise if false, ID is required).

When this happens, despite the data-validate required:false being set and the error classes being hidden, the validation is still occurring and flagging the stID field.

Does the jquery validator plug in have a cache/array of fields which resulted in errors that it determines on submit and possibly isn't being cleared/reset when the resetForm function on our validation is called?

Comment: `$("#input[name='stID']")` , what `#` is doing there, that's not `id` its just a tag, use `$("input[name='stID']")` instead

Comment: This was a simple typo error when giving an example. Your answer provides no real solution to the question posed.

Answer (score 0):

Found the solution, still needed to clear the data attribute associated with these fields producing errors after changing its requirement. This was done by

```
$("#stID").removeData();
```